# C++ toupper () doesn't work

Tags: c++

I don't know why it doesn't work in my program. `tolower()` works correctly. Now I don't know how `toupper()` works, i thought that it works as `tolower()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main ()
{
    using namespace std;

    char ch;


    while (ch != '@')
    {
        cin >> ch;

        if (isdigit (ch))
            cout << "";

        else if (isgraph(ch) )
        {
            ch = tolower (ch);
            cout << ch;
        }

        else
        {
            ch = toupper (ch);
            cout << toupper (ch);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Kuba else statement gets the control in case when a given character has no graphical representation. So there is no any sense to use toupper with such characters.

Comment: `tolower()` - pass an alpha character and get a lower_case letter                               `toupper()` - pass an alpha character and get an upper_case letter

Comment: It absolutely _does_ work. You're just not calling it. You didn't even tell us what you mean by "it doesn't work" and that's why the answerers had to guess. Terrible question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `std::isgraph` returns true if character has graphical symbol. Then again all visible characters will have `true` as output from this function for them, so all will hit `tolower`. What signs do you want to have in uppercase if all will be displayed with `std::tolower`?

Check `std::isgraph` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isgraph).

Answer (score 1):

If you enter a character in your program, weather it is a lower case or upper case letter, it will always end up in this first else statment:

```
else if (isgraph(ch) )
{
    ch = tolower (ch);
    cout << ch;
}
```

So you have to check first if your input is in upper/lower case.
For example [isupper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) and [islower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower) should be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main ()
{
    using namespace std;

    char ch;

    while (ch != '@') {
        cin >> ch;

        if (isdigit (ch)) {
            cout << "this was a digit" << endl;
        }
        else if (isgraph(ch) && isupper(ch)) {
            ch = tolower (ch);
            cout << ch << endl;
        }
        else if (isgraph(ch) && islower(ch))
        {
            ch = toupper (ch);
            cout << ch << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```